# Can I currently (June 2020) travel from Israel to the Taba hotel area and return to Israel?

Tags: covid-19, israel, egypt, student-visas

I am currently a student in Israel.
I have a Israeli student visa in my US passport. 
I would like to take a day trip to Taba - just over the border from eilat.
Is the border open?
Will they let me into Taba?
More importantly: Will Israel let me back in?

Comment: You should contact the Israeli embassy in the US, as the rules are constantly changing. AFAIK, embassy approval is currently required for any non-citizen to enter Israel.

Answer (score 6):

The [Israel Ministry Of Health](https://govextra.gov.il/ministry-of-health/corona/corona-virus-en/faq-corona-en/) published this guidance on returning to Israel:

> ## Who is permitted to enter Israel?
>
> Entry into Israel is permitted to any citizen or resident of Israel, but they are obliged to be isolated upon their arrival from abroad.
> **All** foreign nationals are denied entry to Israel.
> In exceptional cases, one may apply for approval of the Foreign Ministry subject to proof of the ability to remain in home isolation for 14 days upon arrival in Israel.

Therefore it could be very hard/impossible to return.

---

Regarding whether the border is open, it is. The Israel Airports Authority published [updated info on opening times](https://www.iaa.gov.il/he-IL/rashot/Documents/Changes%20to%20hours%20of%20operation%20at%20border%20terminals%20due%20to%20the%20coronavirus%20crisis%20March%202020.pdf) and the border crossing is listed as the *Menachim Begin Terminal* there. The rules/guidance for the border can be viewed [here](https://www.iaa.gov.il/en-US/borders/taba/Pages/default.aspx).

Comment: The quote seems to be self-contradictory. “Citizen **or** resident” appears to cover some foreign nationals while the next sentence excludes them. What's the actual policy?

Comment: @Relaxed, a foreign national is anyone who is not a citizen or a resident of Israel. People who have another citizenship, in addition to the Israeli citizenship/residency, are not considered foreign citizens.

Comment: @SIMEL I am still a bit confused by all this... Is that a typical use of the phrase in Israeli legal parlance? Outside of this context, in English, a (permanent) resident who is not a citizen is still a foreign national.

Comment: @Relaxed I presume it's just a bad/sloppy translation: the intention is quite clearly to allow residents to return, but deny all non-residents entry.

Comment: @Relaxed, maybe it's an Israeli thing, to me it's clear that foreign national means anyone who isn't covered by the 1st statement. Canada is also using a similar language (https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/coronavirus-covid19/travel-restrictions-exemptions.html), giving four criteria for who can enter (only one of them is a Canadian citizen) and then talking about foreign nationals and their criteria of eligibility.